# Рекурсивный подсчет количества строк содержимого файлов в bash

Tags: bash, консоль, командная-строка

В терминале необходимо рекурсивно подсчитать количество строк содержимого файлов из директории lab0, имя которых начинается на 'c',отсортировать вывод по увеличению количества.
**Допустимые команды:** cat,wc,ls,head,tail,echo,sort,grep и любые ключи к ним. Структура имеет вид:

[image: Структура каталога lab0]

Пытался сделать с помощью команд `ls -R | grep ^c`, но выводит текстовое значение - имена файлов. Как запросить путь, чтобы его можно было передать команде wc?

Comment: $(command) можно? Что-то типа `wc $(ls -1 | grep ^c)`

Comment: Можно, но в данном случае проблема будет в том, что я нахожусь в директории lab0/, а файлы начинающиеся на c находятся в директориях уровнем ниже, соответственно, wc не даст никакого результата. Хотя сама команда рабочая, единственная проблема - для нужного результата необходим полный или относительный путь до найденных файлов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто, верная команда:

`wc -l 'echo c* */c*'`

Команда echo должна находится между обратными кавычками, а не одинарными.

Comment: Только это не «рекурсивно», а всего два уровня

Comment: Понял, спасибо за уточнение! Но в данном задании всего два уровня,на практике можно воспользоваться командой find.